# Transistor switch with 2N2222A and cooling fan as load

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, circuit-analysis

I am building a temperature sensor monitoring system with microcontroller.

The input node changes the value if the sensor detects a temperature higher than 70 degrees. I have checked the voltage at the input node, its 3.28V, when its supposed to be high, the fan needs 0.18A to turn on. the voltage at the output node (collector) is 2.2V, but is supposed to be 3.3V with enough current to turn on the fan.

[image]

Could someone suggest a solution to amplify the voltage at the collector and its current.

Thank you

Comment: If that's a 12 V fan, then you want the PN2222A's voltage, measured across the collector and emitter, to be less than 0.2 V or so. In short, measured to ground, the collector should read 0.2 V or less. If not, something is wrong: Measure the voltage across R1 when your input is set to turn the fan on (with a voltmeter) and report the value you get.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed R1 to 330ohm as suggested by nsayer. and I changed the transistor, in case it was broken. The voltage across R1 is 1.87V, when the fan should be On (or when input pin is high). The VCE, when the input pin is low, is 1V; and when the input pin is high (3.3V) is 3.5mV.

Comment: Hmm. Well, with 1.87 V across the resistor when the drive is active suggests a base current of \$\approx 12\:\textrm{mA}\$. I think that's sufficient. However, the \$V_{CE}=1\:\textrm{V}\$ when the input is inactive suggests a rather serious problem. There aren't many parts shown and I can't guess at what isn't shown, so that leaves me to suggest that your PN2222A has been damaged. The fact that your base voltage might be \$1.4\:\textrm{V}\$, input active, with only that base current also doesn't seem right. Should be lower. Hmm.. are you certain of your BJT pinout and usage?

Comment: Please also note that the pinout of a PN2222A is different than a P2N2222A!

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I should clarify that I use 2N2222A -331 not PN-2222A. But since they are both NPN, I didn't update the picture. Now the figure is updated as it is on the board.

Comment: Another thing is the pinout of the Fan, Its 3 pin fan, I followed this pinout instruction. https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/motherboards/motherboard-cpu-3-pin-fan-connector/ The red to collector, black to gnd, yellow to +12.

Comment: I believe that's the problem. The red should go to +12, the black to the collector of the transistor, and the yellow should be NC.

Comment: It finally worked. I really appreciate you guys. I will credit the site in my references :)

Comment: The yellow line is a test line to see if the fan is turning. If you add a pull-up resistor to your logic high supply, you should see one rising edge per revolution. You can use that to set off an alarm if the fan is supposed to be on, but it's not turning.

Answer (score 2):

If the switch were off, then the voltage at the collector of the transistor would be 12 volts. The fact that it's lower than that means that the transistor is conducting, which is bringing the voltage on the near side of the fan down lower than 12.

The way an NPN BJT transistor works is that the current flowing from the base to the emitter will allow a proportionally higher current too flow from the collector to the emitter. What you must figure out is how much current is flowing from the base to the emitter. If that is insufficient to cause sufficient collector current, then you must lower the resistor value.

What you likely want is to get the transistor into saturation. This means that there is insufficient voltage (because of the impedance of the load - the fan) to drive more current through the transistor. Increasing the base current won't make more collector current flow in this situation and the transistor will (more or less) act like a closed switch.

That said, if your input is a 5 volt logic high, then you're sending 33 mA (or so - the base-emitter junction won't be zero volts, after all), which "ought" to be enough to saturate that transistor.

I wonder if maybe 33 mA is too much current for the microcontroller pin in question. If so, you potentially might have (or might soon) blow that pin. You might consider increasing that resistor value. 220Ω or 330Ω are more like values I'd use under similar circumstances.

Comment: Agreed. Even at 3.3V input on R1, the current should be 22 mA (or at least 17 mA when taking the base-emitter diode drop into account), which should be plenty. Either the micro can't source enough current, or one of the components is broken, or the circuit has been wired incorrectly.

Comment: @Dampmaskin yeah - and now that I look at that, I wonder if 33 mA is too much for whatever is on the other end.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed R1 to 330ohm as suggested by nsayer. and I changed the transistor, in case it was broken. I measured the current from base to emitter and current from base to collector, when the input pin is 3.3V, the current is 7.28mA. and the current from base to collector is 6.15mA.

Comment: There should be no current from the base to the collector. The current of interest is from the collector to the emitter - that should be much, much higher.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. the ICE when input is low is 0.21mA when  the input is high is 0.32mA.

Comment: I've got no explanation for your observations other than something being broken in your circuit.